# Cross cutting concern logging

Tags: design-patterns, cross-cutting-concerns

I want to log certain information about methods being executed, I considered AOP which was okay, knocked up a demo, but I really need to log specific information about each method, think of it as additional info related to the call.

Now the options i considered where just log it in each method, but i think its going to pollute the code, last resort, perhaps

Or i create a class that maps methods to information that needs to be logged, and use AOP to log this info.

What do you guys think?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example on what would differ in every methods?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach might be the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)/[Interceptor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interceptor_pattern) but results in an increased coding effort:

```
interface IComponent
{
    int Foo(int input);
}

class Component : IComponent
{
    public int Foo(int input)
    {
        return input * 2;
    }
}

class LoggingComponent: IComponent
{
    private readonly IComponent target;

    public LoggingComponent(IComponent target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public int Foo(int input)
    {
        // ToDo: Add logging before method call

        int returnValue = this.target.Foo(input);

        // ToDo: Add logging after method call

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Using this approach requires implementing a lot of logging classes for all targets you want to log method calls and input/return values. In addition you can not log what happens inside the methods of the target the decorator/interceptor forwards to.

Answer (score 0):

You can also think about using the Ambient Context Pattern to implement cross-cutting concerns. There is a nice blog about it: [Ambient Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx).